# Slice is not working correctly | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, splice

In my constructor I have this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    showCount: 4,
    event: [],
    customer: [],
    lock: []
  }
}
```

In my `componentDidMount` I have this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { data } = this.props
  axios.get('http://34.248.65.20:3000/customers').then(res => {
    this.setState({
      res,
      data: res.data
    })
  })

  axios.get('http://34.248.65.20:3000/events').then(res => {
    this.setState({
      res,
      data: res.data
    })
  })

  axios.get('http://34.248.65.20:3000/locks').then(res => {
    this.setState({
      res,
      data: res.data
    })
  })
}
```

And in my render I have this:

```
const { event, customer, lock, data } = this.state
const keyedCustomers = _.keyBy(customer, '_id')
const keyedLocks = _.keyBy(lock, '_id')

const events = event
  .slice(0, this.state.showCount)
  .map((event, i) =>
    <EventItem
      key={i}
      event={event}
      customer={keyedCustomers[event.customer] || {}}
      lock={keyedLocks[event.lock] || {}}
    />
  )
console.log(events) // A lot of object
```

Here's the object `events`:
[image]

But I dont see any of my events (one event is basically a `li`) in my app. And I thought that this will just display four of my events by default (`showCount: 4`). Because I want to have a button that will display all of them later.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers!

Comment: Please add more code to illustrate the issue. What is **event** in your render function? Did you mean `this.state.event` ?

Comment: do you see errors in the console?

Comment: @DanielAndrei I've added more code.

Comment: @MaximKuzmin Nopp, no errors :/

Comment: @MartinNordström you need to post example of 'event' object (you can check it via debugger or console.log)

Comment: @MartinNordström, where are you setting `event` ? Your `ComponentDidMount` api calls are setting data but really can't understand what is inside data. Did you `console.log` `event` after api calls ?

Comment: hehehe well this is really awkward. I let my friend check my code and he started to change names on stuff, therefor there was no data coming out.. I've updated the code.... Sorry guys.

Answer (score 3):

If your `res` is not like `{event: []}`, you should do:

```
 axios.get('http://34.248.65.20:3000/events').then(res => {
    this.setState({
      ...
      event: res.data
    })
  })
```